# Passing data between various technologies

Tags: c#, java, c++, node.js

I'm creating client-server application in which I'm planning to incorporate at least 2 technologies. Recently I've read lot about `node.js` performance in handling web communication, so I wanted to give it a try.

The problem is, writing the whole service in node.js is rather not acceptable (following the rule: "Choose proper technology to the task, not proper task to technology"), so I want to create only web interface in node.js (both client and server side) and to implement the rest in java/c#/C++.

My first thought was to launch a separate processes of net-interface and core-app and communicate between them using localhost sockets. But I wondered if there is another way to do that as sockets have their limitations (buffer size and so on).

So the question is: Is it possible to force communication between processes with various technologies **on the same machine?**

Thanks

Comment: You can read here about several techniques: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication Using sockets is the best one imho, most reliable and fault tolerant.

Comment: CORBA is what you should look for

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to force communication between various technologies by using **Web Services.**

In my opinion, it is more robust to pass data between various technologies using Web Services rather than do it using javascript. You know, the user can simply use his browser with javascript disabled.

Every mature programming language supports web services.

Moreover, if you want to integrate different applications written in the same language such as Java, you can use the Java Messaging Service. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can use various IPC (interprocess communication) techniques but using sockets will have the added benefit of enabling you to move your components to different servers. You can then use SOAP or REST services over sockets.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to achieve this, Web Services since legacy have been using XML to have data communication between 2 different technological systems. **Web Services** itself is one of the very good ways to impose communication between different technologies, rather theese days all good programming languages go for implementing Web Services.

Other than that you have got techniques where you can involve hardware communication using chaining i.e., process swap-and-switch, IPC(Inter-process Communication), Script Engines(JavaScript), XML Involution(Techniques similar to what ATM machines use to sync data).